# I can't delete an archive

Tags: windows

recently Windows defender detected me some viruses in a rar archive, the point of the situation is that probably by quarantining or deleting it, I can no longer delete it manually. I tried to install Unlocker, do commands from the CMD but nothing ... How can I do it?

Comment: I add that even clicking on Start actions on windows defender does not work in addition to loading infinitely

Comment: Defender will delete it after a few weeks in quarantine.

Comment: I don't think he quarantined him because every day I always get the notification that he has detected this threat

Comment: Where in the file system is this archive?